# running the same animation multiple times with libGDX

Tags: animation, libgdx

I use this code in `touchDown` method to animate an object with an animation made in Blender. `controller` is `AnimationController` and is instantiated at the start of application. I noticed that using this approach I cannot run the same animation 2 times in a row. It can only run once. What is the correct approach to run the same animation multiple times in a row? Thanks for help.

```
//touchDown method

        controller.animate(animationName,0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instruct the controller to allow the same animation:

```
controller.allowSameAnimation = true;
```

See: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/utils/AnimationController.html#allowSameAnimation

Comment: Thank you. I think I am reading a book you reviewed Libgdx Cross-platform Game Development Cookbook. Great stuff. Would you mind looking at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383397/spotlight-not-working-in-libgdx ?